# Regexp change with Substitute apache instrument in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache

I want to change strings on my site pages like:

```
<hr style="width:50%;">

    
                    <center>
```

to:

```
<hr style="width:50%;"><p class="somenew"></p><center>
```

You can see that these strings include spaces, tabs, new line symbols, so i use (\s+) in my regexp to make a substitute with htaccess:

```
Substitute 's|<hr style="width:50%;">(\s+)<center>|<hr style="width:50%;"><p class="somenew"></p><center>|i'
```

Though mod_substitute is enabled and works (other substitutions in the same .htaccess, that do not contain regexp, work fine), this particalur substitute is not working. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've generated an example of what you want to accomplish on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oVAaCZ/1). The generalized rule is:

```bash
(<hr.+?>)(?:\s+)(<center>)
```

And the substitution is:

```bash
$1<p class="somenew"></p>$2
```

Per the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) for `mod_substitute`, this is the appropriate `.htaccess` syntax to use to accomplish your goal:

```bash
<Location "/">
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    SubstituteMaxLineLength 10m
    Substitute "s|(<hr.+?>)(?:\s+)(<center>)|$1<p class=\"somenew\"></p>$2|i"
</Location>
```

If this still does not work for you, let me know and provide additional details for further troubleshooting.